# Collect all Similar Persons to One Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, graph

I have a person with several Id's.
Some of them in Column Id1 and Some of them in Id2.
I want to collect all the same persons Id's to one group.

If id1=10, is in the same row with id2=20. so it's mean that person with id1=10 he is the same person like id2=20.

The Input and Output example:

#### Input

```
Id1     Id2
---     ---
10      20
10      30
30      30
10      40

50      70
60      50
70      70
```

#### Output

```
NewId   OldId
-----   -----
1       10
1       20
1       30
1       40

2       50
2       60
2       70
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be better to make such calculations in iterative manner.

The "*issue*" of such solution is that, in case of large source table, the output table will contains all the rows. But, actually, this is the benefit also: in case of large source table, such code will work much more faster, that recursions.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#src') is not null drop table #src;
create table #src (id1 int not null, id2 int)

if object_id('tempdb..#rez') is not null drop table #rez;
create table #rez (id int not null, chainid int not null);

declare @chainId int;

insert #src
values (10, 20), (10, 30), (30, 30), (10, 40), (50, 70), (60, 50), (70, 70)
--values (4457745,255714),(4457745,2540222),(2540222,4457745),(255714,4457745)

set @chainId = 1

while 1 = 1
begin
    insert #rez(id, chainid)
    select top 1 id1, @chainId
    from #src
    where
        Id1 NOT IN (select Id from #rez)
        and id2 NOT IN (select Id from #rez)

    if @@rowcount = 0 break

    while 1 = 1
    begin
        insert #rez(id, chainid)

        select id1, @chainid
        from #src
        where
            id2 in (select id from #rez where chainid = @chainId)
            and id1 not in (select id from #rez where chainid = @chainId)

        union

        select id2, @chainId
        from #src
        where
            id1 in (select id from #rez where chainid = @chainId)
            and id2 not in (select id from #rez where chainid = @chainId)

        if @@rowcount = 0 break
    end

    select @chainId = @chainId + 1
end

select [NewId] = chainid, OldID = id
from #rez 
order by 1, 2;
```

In some details, the "logic" of the script is the following:

- set new ID (chainid) initial value (ex. 1)

  - get the first entry which was not found yet (external cycle)

    - find and store all related to it (in both columns) (internal cycle)
  - increment the new ID
  - find next entry which is not in the result table
  - continue till have data to work
- return sorted result

Comment: BTW, checked with both your data samples: works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Here I adapted my old answer from a similar SO question [How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254260/4116017).

This variant doesn't use a cursor or explicit loop, but uses a single recursive query.

Essentially, it treats the data as edges in a graph and traverses recursively all edges of the graph, stopping when the loop is detected. Then it puts all found loops in groups and gives each group a number.

See the detailed explanations of how it works below. I recommend you to run the query CTE-by-CTE and examine each intermediate result to understand what it does.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID1 int NOT NULL, ID2 int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @T (ID1, ID2) VALUES
(10, 20),
(10, 30),
(30, 30),
(10, 40),
(50, 70),
(60, 50),
(70, 70),
(4457745, 255714),
(4457745,2540222),
(2540222,4457745),
( 255714,4457745);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Ids
AS
(
    SELECT ID1 AS ID
    FROM @T

    UNION

    SELECT ID2 AS ID
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM @T
    WHERE ID1 <> ID2

    UNION

    SELECT ID2 AS ID1, ID1 AS ID2
    FROM @T
    WHERE ID1 <> ID2
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(CTE_Ids.ID AS varchar(8000)) AS AnchorID
        ,ID1
        ,ID2
        ,CAST(
            ',' + CAST(ID1 AS varchar(8000)) + 
            ',' + CAST(ID2 AS varchar(8000)) + 
            ',' AS varchar(8000)) AS IdPath
        ,1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Ids ON CTE_Ids.ID = CTE_Pairs.ID1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CTE_Recursive.AnchorID
        ,CTE_Pairs.ID1
        ,CTE_Pairs.ID2
        ,CAST(
            CTE_Recursive.IdPath + 
            CAST(CTE_Pairs.ID2 AS varchar(8000)) +
            ',' AS varchar(8000)) AS IdPath
        ,CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.ID2 = CTE_Pairs.ID1
    WHERE
        CTE_Recursive.IdPath NOT LIKE 
            CAST('%,' + CAST(CTE_Pairs.ID2 AS varchar(8000)) + ',%' AS varchar(8000))
)
,CTE_RecursionResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorID, ID1, ID2
    FROM CTE_Recursive
)
,CTE_CleanResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorID, ID1 AS ID
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult

    UNION

    SELECT AnchorID, ID2 AS ID
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult
)
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CA_Data.XML_Value) AS [NewID]
    ,CTE_Ids.ID AS [OldID]
    ,CA_Data.XML_Value AS GroupMembers
FROM
    CTE_Ids
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CAST(CTE_CleanResult.ID AS nvarchar(max)) + ','
        FROM CTE_CleanResult
        WHERE CTE_CleanResult.AnchorID = CTE_Ids.ID
        ORDER BY CTE_CleanResult.ID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS CA_XML(XML_Value)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CA_XML.XML_Value.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ) AS CA_Data(XML_Value)
ORDER BY [NewID], [OldID];
```

**Result**

```
+-------+---------+-------------------------+
| NewID |  OldID  |      GroupMembers       |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+
|     1 |      10 | 10,20,30,40,            |
|     1 |      20 | 10,20,30,40,            |
|     1 |      30 | 10,20,30,40,            |
|     1 |      40 | 10,20,30,40,            |
|     2 |  255714 | 255714,2540222,4457745, |
|     2 | 2540222 | 255714,2540222,4457745, |
|     2 | 4457745 | 255714,2540222,4457745, |
|     3 |      50 | 50,60,70,               |
|     3 |      60 | 50,60,70,               |
|     3 |      70 | 50,60,70,               |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+
```

### How it works

**`CTE_Ids`**

`CTE_Ids` gives the list of all Identifiers that appear in both `ID1` and `ID2` columns. 
Since they can appear in any order we `UNION` both columns together. `UNION` also removes any duplicates.

```
+---------+
|   ID    |
+---------+
|      10 |
|      20 |
|      30 |
|      40 |
|      50 |
|      60 |
|      70 |
|  255714 |
| 2540222 |
| 4457745 |
+---------+
```

**`CTE_Pairs`**

`CTE_Pairs` gives the list of all edges of the graph in both directions. Again, `UNION` is used to remove any duplicates.

```
+---------+---------+
|   ID1   |   ID2   |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |      20 |
|      10 |      30 |
|      10 |      40 |
|      20 |      10 |
|      30 |      10 |
|      40 |      10 |
|      50 |      60 |
|      50 |      70 |
|      60 |      50 |
|      70 |      50 |
|  255714 | 4457745 |
| 2540222 | 4457745 |
| 4457745 |  255714 |
| 4457745 | 2540222 |
+---------+---------+
```

**`CTE_Recursive`**

`CTE_Recursive` is the main part of the query that recursively traverses the graph starting from each unique Identifier. 
These starting rows are produced by the first part of `UNION ALL`. 
The second part of `UNION ALL` recursively joins to itself linking `ID2` to `ID1`.
Since we pre-made `CTE_Pairs` with all edges written in both directions, we can always link only `ID2` to `ID1` and we'll get all paths in the graph.
At the same time the query builds `IdPath` - a string of comma-delimited Identifiers that have been traversed so far.
It is used in the `WHERE` filter:

```
CTE_Recursive.IdPath NOT LIKE 
    CAST('%,' + CAST(CTE_Pairs.ID2 AS varchar(8000)) + ',%' AS varchar(8000))
```

As soon as we come across the Identifier that had been included in the Path before, the recursion stops as the list of connected nodes is exhausted.
`AnchorID` is the starting Identifier for the recursion, it will be used later to group results. 
`Lvl` is not really used, I included it for better understanding of what is going on.

```
+----------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-----+
| AnchorID |   ID1   |   ID2   |          IdPath          | Lvl |
+----------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-----+
|       10 |      10 |      20 | ,10,20,                  |   1 |
|       10 |      10 |      30 | ,10,30,                  |   1 |
|       10 |      10 |      40 | ,10,40,                  |   1 |
|       20 |      20 |      10 | ,20,10,                  |   1 |
|       30 |      30 |      10 | ,30,10,                  |   1 |
|       40 |      40 |      10 | ,40,10,                  |   1 |
|       50 |      50 |      60 | ,50,60,                  |   1 |
|       50 |      50 |      70 | ,50,70,                  |   1 |
|       60 |      60 |      50 | ,60,50,                  |   1 |
|       70 |      70 |      50 | ,70,50,                  |   1 |
|   255714 |  255714 | 4457745 | ,255714,4457745,         |   1 |
|  2540222 | 2540222 | 4457745 | ,2540222,4457745,        |   1 |
|  4457745 | 4457745 |  255714 | ,4457745,255714,         |   1 |
|  4457745 | 4457745 | 2540222 | ,4457745,2540222,        |   1 |
|  2540222 | 4457745 |  255714 | ,2540222,4457745,255714, |   2 |
|   255714 | 4457745 | 2540222 | ,255714,4457745,2540222, |   2 |
|       70 |      50 |      60 | ,70,50,60,               |   2 |
|       60 |      50 |      70 | ,60,50,70,               |   2 |
|       40 |      10 |      20 | ,40,10,20,               |   2 |
|       40 |      10 |      30 | ,40,10,30,               |   2 |
|       30 |      10 |      20 | ,30,10,20,               |   2 |
|       30 |      10 |      40 | ,30,10,40,               |   2 |
|       20 |      10 |      30 | ,20,10,30,               |   2 |
|       20 |      10 |      40 | ,20,10,40,               |   2 |
+----------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-----+
```

**`CTE_CleanResult`**

`CTE_CleanResult` leaves only relevant parts from `CTE_Recursive` and again merges both `ID1` and `ID2` using `UNION`.

```
+----------+---------+
| AnchorID |   ID    |
+----------+---------+
|       10 |      10 |
|       10 |      20 |
|       10 |      30 |
|       10 |      40 |
|       20 |      10 |
|       20 |      20 |
|       20 |      30 |
|       20 |      40 |
|  2540222 |  255714 |
|  2540222 | 2540222 |
|  2540222 | 4457745 |
|   255714 |  255714 |
|   255714 | 2540222 |
|   255714 | 4457745 |
|       30 |      10 |
|       30 |      20 |
|       30 |      30 |
|       30 |      40 |
|       40 |      10 |
|       40 |      20 |
|       40 |      30 |
|       40 |      40 |
|  4457745 |  255714 |
|  4457745 | 2540222 |
|  4457745 | 4457745 |
|       50 |      50 |
|       50 |      60 |
|       50 |      70 |
|       60 |      50 |
|       60 |      60 |
|       60 |      70 |
|       70 |      50 |
|       70 |      60 |
|       70 |      70 |
+----------+---------+
```

**Final SELECT**

Now we need to build a string of comma-separated `ID` values for each `AnchorID`. 
`CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML` does it.
`DENSE_RANK()` calculates the `NewID` numbers for each `AnchorID`.

---

This query builds a full path for each identifier, which is not really necessary.

It is possible to make the overall solution more efficient by running this query once for each group/subgraph, in a loop.

Pick a single starting Identifier (add `WHERE ID = 10` to `CTE_Ids` and `CTE_Pairs`), then delete from the source table all identifiers that were appended to this group. Repeat until the big table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to go about this, but maybe this will be a start.

I used CTEs to first switch round the Ids, so the left column was less than the right column (Filtered).

Then I made a table that contained all of the lower values (from the left column) together with any value higher than them (from the right column) (FilteredUp).

FilteredDown removes any cases where there exists a lower example (eg you have 30,30 as one row, but this is removed as there exists a 10,20 row) and also makes sure we have all the left values in the right column (eg 10,10 and 50,50).

Finally I created the new Ids using ROW_NUMBER():

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Id1 INT, Id2 INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp 
    VALUES(10,20),(10,30),(30,30),(10,40),(50,70),(60,50),(70,70)
END

 SELECT * FROM #Temp

;With Filtered AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN Id1 <= Id2 THEN Id1 ELSE Id2 END AS Id1, CASE WHEN Id1 >= Id2 THEN Id1 ELSE Id2 END AS Id2 FROM #Temp
), 
FilteredUp AS(
    SELECT id1, Id2 AS Up FROM Filtered 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f.id1, fu.Id2 FROM FilteredUp f
        JOIN Filtered fu ON f.Up = fu.Id1 AND f.Up < fu.Id2  
),
FilteredDown AS (
    SELECT f.Id1, f.Id2 FROM Filtered f
        LEFT JOIN FilteredUp fu ON f.Id1 = fu.Up
        WHERE fu.Id1 IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT f.Id1, f.Id1 AS Id2 FROM Filtered f
        LEFT JOIN FilteredUp fu ON f.Id1 = fu.Up
        WHERE fu.Id1 IS NULL 
),
RowNumber AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id1) AS NewId, Id1 FROM FilteredDown
    GROUP BY Id1
)
SELECT rn.NewId, fd.Id2 AS OldId FROM RowNumber rn
    JOIN FilteredDown fd ON rn.Id1 = fd.Id1
```

Comment: there is a problem for the input: (4457745,255714),(4457745,2540222),(2540222,4457745),(255714,4457745).  It should return for all of the id's the same NewId

Comment: But it is very weird, if i will change 4457745 to 10 (or a small number) it will work. do you know Why?

Comment: Sam? can you tell me why for this insert it not working?:(4457745,255714),(4457745,2540222),(2540222,4457745),(255714‌​,4457745)

Comment: use a **bigint**

Comment: Sandr's answer is more complete (and much better), I didn't consider the possibility of a chain as in your example.

because 255714 & 2540222 are both smaller than 4457745 and there is nothing directly linking them together, they are missed by mine. Whereas Sandr's solution will check against this chain.